# Simulate Homogeneous Poisson where each event is uniform

Tags: self-study, simulation, random-generation, poisson-process

The problem is the following:

> Buses arrives according to a Homogeneous Poisson with arrival tax of 5
>   per hour. Each bus can contain 20, 21, 22... 40 passengers with eaqual
>   probability.
>
> - Write an algorithm to simulate the number of passengers in 1 hour.
> - Write an algorithm to obtain 500 values of passengers.

I know that I can generate a random poisson variable like this:`- log(runif(1)) / lambda`

But I don't know how to combine this with the passengers values.

Also, if anyone can indicate how to solve this without simulation would be a great help.

I program in R.

Comment: add self-study tag since it's a home work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called the [discrete compound Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_Poisson_distribution#Discrete_compound_Poisson_distribution) or process. It can be sampled by using something called [Panjer recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panjer_recursion).

The easiest way is to simulate, which most people end up doing. You sample the number of buses $n_i$ from Poisson, where $i$ is the simulation index. Next, you sample $n_i$ numbers $m_1,m_2,\dots,m_{n_i}$ from the uniform distribution [20,40], and add them up $S_i=\sum_{j=1}^{n_i}m_j$. Do this 500 times to obtain the sample requested.

Panjer recursion allows to obtain the distribution of the compound random variable, from which you can sample $S_i$ directly without the inner loop on $n_i$. That's probably an overkill for this assignment. This is done in practice for expensive inner distributions or large scales when your task is to obtain a distribution. In your case you just need a tiny sample of 500 values, so the simulation is right approach.